# Help with a basic Trigonometry Question

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Can someone please show me how to work out the answer without a calculator?

Comment: Hints: [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) and $\sin(30^\circ) = \sin(150^\circ)$ (check this via the unit circle).

Answer (score 4):

As @Bye_World mentioned use Law of sines as $$\frac { 4 }{ \sin { B }  } =\frac { 10 }{ \sin { 150 }  } \\ \sin { B=\frac { 4 }{ 10 } \sin { 150=\frac { 2 }{ 5 } \sin { 30 } =\frac { 1 }{ 5 }  }  } $$

Answer (score 0):

Here, we need to show that $sin B=\dfrac{1}{5}$

We' ll use law of sines
[image]

In this problem,
$$\dfrac{sinA}{10}=\dfrac{sinB}{4}$$
$$\dfrac{sin 150°}{10}=\dfrac{sinB}{4}$$
$$sinB=\dfrac{sin(150°)×4}{10}$$
$$=\dfrac{sin(180°-30°)×4}{10}$$
As, $sin(\pi-\theta)=sin\theta$

So,$$sinB=\dfrac{sin30°×4}{10}$$
$$=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{\not2}×\not4}{10}$$
$$=\dfrac{2}{10}=\dfrac{1}{5}$$
Thus, $$sinB=\dfrac{1}{5}$$
I hope it' ll help.